Unable to see logs in Release pipeline in Azure DevOps
While deploying a NodeJS app in Azure DevOps, we are not getting logs under 'Agent Job' for tasks. This however is working in another free version of the account and the same is not working on official account. The PAT token for the agent is also having same access scope. Not sure what I am missing. Only below screen appears but no in depth diagnostics logs.


What exactly do you mean by in depth diagnostics logs? In your screenshot I see both the Download all logs (release) and the small blue icon for downloading the logs for the Command Line Script task. What is missing?

Hi @Salman, Have you got a chance to check the answer below to enable debug logs for release pipelines? Hope the information may help resolve your query in this post. Thx for the sharing.

Hi @Salman, May I know if the answer below to enable debug logs for release pipelines can help resolve your query in this post. Thx.

Hi @AlvinZhao-MSFT the below solution didnt work, the issue seems to be around proxy , we are still inspecting it

Thanks for taking time to share the update.

We are unable to get these debug logs when using new URL - https://dev.azure.com/go*** , however it works on old URL - https://go***.visualstudio.com/ , Can you give some pointers and solution to this?

May I know if your organization has enabled Use the new URL:https://dev.azure.com/go*** in Organization settings?

If by depth diagnostics logs you meant the logs enabled by system diagnostics, for a release pipeline, you may add the variable system.debug as true to collect the debug logs in purple like those in the screenshot below.


